# Output Graph, CSV & Excel file from PHP

Tags: php

I have a PHP code which will generate Graph & HTML table which is working fine. - Main_data.php
CSV output PHP is working fine. - CSV.php
Excel output PHP is working fine.

How to output all three reports when running Main_data.php?

I tried to include Csv.php in Main_data.php. I am not able to produce results from main_data.php.

Any suggestions on how to implement that function into my script?

Answer (score 0):

Make functions `displayGraph()` and `displayCSV()`.
Put them in one file by copying your codes from `main_data.php` and `csv.php`, include that file in a file you want to display graph and CSV from and execute the functions.

Comment: Thanks Nikola. I created test.php file and I copied csv.php to displaycsv() and excel.php to displayexcel(). I created chk.php file and included test.php and called functions displaycsv() & displayexcel(). Only one function executed. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I need two functions to execute. ie diplaycsv and display excel. Thanks for your help.